# How to structure data for orders in firestore?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a food delivery app. I am facing hurdles while **querying** the data for the order **status** inside the **order Id**.

Here is my database design:

```
Users (collections)
------> user id (documents)
----------> orders(object)

// Orders is a nested object. You can find an image of this down below.
orders{
   "order_id":{
     created_at: <time>
     order_items: <array>
     status: <string> 
  }
}
```

Is there a way in which I can receive the order status of items that are pending?

Here is the image of the database[image: Firestore DataBase Image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be best if the `orders` is made a sub-collection (or a separate root level collection) so you can query orders with a particular status. The database structure would be like:

```
users -> {userId} -> orders -> {orderId}
(col)     (doc)       (col)      (doc)
```

Otherwise with current structure you would have to fetch the complete document and the sort orders using Javascript. Also note that a single document has a [1 MB limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) so you are limiting the number of orders a user can have.

Once you have move the each order to a document in 'orders' sub-collection, you can query pending orders like this:

```js
const q = query(collection(db, "users", userId, "orders"), where("status", "==", pending));

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```

Comment: Hi, quick question, my first order is assigned a value of 100,000 and for each order i check the count of my database and increment that value with 1. My problem is when 2 orders are placed at the same time, they get assigned the same value. How do i fix this?

Comment: @kd12345 can you please post a new question with more details of your question and a screenshot of database sctructure?

Comment: Hi, here you go. I posted a question and someone closed it for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77279523/assigning-documents-in-firestore-a-different-order-number

Answer (score 0):

Your document structure does not make such a query possible.  You would have to get the document, write code to pull the orders out of it, then filter those orders in memory in your app.

With Firestore, if you are trying to find a subset of some items based on a filter criteria, you should model those items as individual documents in a collection, not all together in the same document.  That will allow you to select only the items you need.

For all questions about modeling data, the best data model is the one that meets the needs of your queries.  You should understand your queries first before modeling the data.

Answer (score -1):

As also @DougStevenson mentioned in his answer, your actual document structure doesn't allow you to get all pending orders using a query.

As @Dharmaraj also mentioned in his answer, a possible solution might be to store the orders in a collection. However, this solution is a little costly since you'll have to pay a document read for each document that is returned by your query.

Bear in mind, that is nothing wrong with nesting the user orders in a document. I personally would **not** nest the orders in an array under the user object but I'll create a separate top-level collection and a sub-collection. It's true that you are limited to 1 MiB of data in a single document, but you can refactor the database by sharding the orders over multiple documents as below:

```
Firestore-root
  |
  --- allOrders (collection)
       |
       --- $uid (document)
            |
            --- userOrders (collection)
                  |
                  --- 01-2021 (document) // month-year
                       |
                       --- orders (array)
                            |
                            --- #153108AB
                                  |
                                  --- createdAt: ...
                                  |
                                  --- order_items: ...
```

Using this structure, you'll be able to use 1 MiB of data for each month in the year. We are talking now about 12 MiB of data. That's a lot for storing orders.

If you think that 12 MiB of data won't be enough, you can consider then sharding the orders per day, meaning that instead of having 12 MiB of data, you'll have **365 MiB**. I can guarantee you that is enough space for a single user/year. Now, all you have to do is to download the documents and do the filtering on the client.

Imagine how many orders can fit into 365 MiB of data. Are you willing to pay a document read for each one of them if you are adding them into a collection?

I have also written an article, a few days ago regarding this topic, which is called:

- [How to reduce Firestore costs?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-reduce-firestore-costs-8cb712473e83)

Comment: Hey Ayush! Did you also try the solution in my answer?