# Assigning documents in Firestore a different order number

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

How to do i assign different order numbers to each document in Firestore without duplicating the same order number again?

Before i call addDoc(), i create a query to get the count of documents in my order collection (eg.4). Then when adding a document, i add that count(4) to 1,000,000 (1,000,004).

My problem is that if 2 orders are placed at the same exact time, the count(4) are the same for both and they both get assigned the same order number(1,000,004). How do i fix this?

Comment: With Firestore, you really shouldn't implement things like this. Please read the discussions in the duplicate questions.  It just doesn't scale in the way that Firestore requires.  Consider instead using a server timestamp field in your documents for sorting them chronologically.

Comment: @DougStevenson, this is not my point, each order in firestore is assigned a uid but i dont want to display the order number as uid since it is very long. hence why i am asigning each order a orderId

Comment: There is an answer in one of the duplicates that still applies. Store the count in a document and increment it with a transaction when you add a new document. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55082045/807126